# Frobenius isomorphism for Hopf algebras 

Tags: hopf-algebras

It is known that a finite dimensional Hopf algebra $H$ over a field $k$ is a Frobenius algebra. Thus there is an isomorphism $H \cong H^\ast$ of left $H$-modules.

**Question:** Is it possible to write down such an isomorphism entirely in terms of the Hopf algebra, i.e. by product, coproduct, unit, counit and involution ?

Comment: Do you consider cointegrals to be part of The Hopf Algebra™? They are uniquely determined (up to scalars) from equations which can be written down in terms of the Hopf algebra structure maps, just as the antipode is... If you do, then yes.

Comment: How would the isomorphism look then ? 

Comment: I don't think this can be done using left integrals of $H$ itself. But if $\lambda$ is a left integral of $H^{\ast}$, then the linear map $H\to H^{\ast},\ a\mapsto a\lambda$ is an $H$-left linear isomorphism.

Comment: But the existence of such an integral is guaranteed by the Hopf Algebra axioms and the finite dimensionality, isn't it ? So isn't it possible to express this integral (and hence the isomorphism) in  terms of the Hopf algebra's structure maps ? 

Comment: It is a theorem that a finite dimensional Hopf algebra has (up to scalars) a unique integral in $H^*$; the space it spans can be described as the coinvariant subspace in $H^*$ for some Hopf module structure (this is explained in standard placed, like Sweedler's book or Susan Montgomery's)... It is not obvious what you mean by *express*, so it is hard to answer your question—I do doubt there is a universal expression for the isomorphism in the category generated by the structure maps of the Hopf algebra, though.

Comment: @unknown: Do you want a functor? If so, from which category?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if there is a closed formula for the   Frobenius isomorphism that only uses the structure maps noted in the  question. But according to Mariano's comment there seems to be little  hope. 

Comment: @unknown: If there was a closed formula, there would be a functor from the category of finite-dimensional Hopf algebras (with all Hopf algebra morphisms, not just isomorphisms). I think this could be easily led to a contradiction, although I don't see how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer but a lengthy comment.

The proofs for the $H$-modul ismorphism $H \cong H^\ast$ I know of use (some variant of) the $H$-module isomorphism $I_L(H^\ast) \otimes_k H \cong H^\ast$ where 
$$I_L(H^\ast) = \lbrace g \in H^\ast \mid \forall f\in H^\ast: f\ast g = f(1) \cdot g \rbrace$$ is the space of left integrals of $H^\ast$ ($f \ast g$ is the convolution). A dimension argument shows that $I_L(H^\ast)$ is one-dimensional. If $\lambda$ is a non-zero left integral then $I_L(H^\ast) = k\cdot \lambda \cong k$ yields $H \cong H^\ast$ as left $H$-modules. This is just the isomorphism described by darij.

The problem is that the proof doesn't yield a formula for such a $\lambda$. Choose a $k$-basis $\lbrace e_1=1,e_2,...,e_n\rbrace$ of $H$ and suppose $\Delta(e_k) = \sum_{i,j}d_{ij}^{(k)}\cdot e_i \otimes e_j$. Set $D^{(k)} = (d_{ij}^{(k)}-\delta_{i,1}\cdot \delta_{kj})_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$. Expressing $\lambda$ as linear combination of the dual basis then leads to the system of linear equations 
$D^{(k)} x = 0$ $(k=1,...,n)$. As pointed out by Mariano it has a unique solution (up to scalars). Again, this is no closed formula, but it can be used in practise to compute integrals.